# Visual studio 2013 pending changes window not comments field

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 together with TFS 2012 since a few weeks. Until yesterday I always had the Comments Textbox in the "Pending Changes Window". Now it has dissapeared and I can not find a way to get it back. This is a serious problem since it is mandatory to give comments to every checkin.

Can anybody tell me how to get the comments textbox back.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't collapsed? Look for "▷ Comment" in the Pending Changes window.

Comment: CodeCaster, thanks for the quick reply, but it is not collapsed. All the other items ("Related Work Items", "Included Changes" and "Excluded Changes") are present but not the "Comment" item.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a screenshot of your Pending Changes window?  It should be right here:

[image]

Comment: I can not post images yet, but my Pending Changes Window looks almost the same: there is no "Comment" text with corresponding Textbox.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to struggle through this issue myself and found there is very little information out there on how to resolve it.

For my situation, what finally fixed the issue was removing the 2012 version of TFS Power Tools and upgrading to the 2013 version.  There are several members of my team who are using the combination of TFS Power Tools 2012 and VS 2013 with no issues, I'm the only one who saw this.

I suspect that this was not a power tools issue as much as it was a problem with VS caching some TFS data locally.  I tried a number of options to clear caches in both VS and TFS and nothing worked until I did this uninstall/reinstall.

Regardless, after the TFS power tools upgrade and a reboot, the Comment box was back.  Hope that helps!

EDIT: I should also point out that not only was my "Comments" section missing, I also had no "Policy Warnings" section which we require on certain projects of our TFS.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue right after installing NCrunch 2.4.
Uninstalling it brought my comment box back.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. Vanished today. Have not installed anything for weeks. I had 3 Visual Studio 2013 up at the same time. 2 was bugged, 1 was not. I closed the 2 buggy ones, and then the working one hoping that last one would save its settings last. Did not work. Now I have no way of adding comments. I can check in anything without the policy blocking me like it normally does when I do not enter a comment.

UPDATE: A simple reboot of the client solved it. The Comment is back!

[image: Comment is back!]

[image: No Comment field]